# Crypt Status does not equal kCCSuccess

Tags: objective-c, web-services, encryption, aes

I have been working on decryption for some time now and cannot get it to work. When I encrypt using the following code:

```
private static string Decrypt(string plainText, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
  {
    RijndealManaged aesEncryption = new RijndealManaged();
    aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize; //keySize is 256
    aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
    aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ACSII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedString)).Split(',')[0]);
    aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ACSII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedString)).Split(',')[1]);
    byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainStr);
    ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
  }
```

passing the name "Anthony" as the plainText I get `uRO2DBKAhFsOed/p10dz+w==`

and I decrypt using

```
-(NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL/* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess){
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free( buffer ); //free the buffer
return nil;
}
```

but I get nothing in return. The code gets up to the `if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess){` line and it does not go into the if statement. So the the decryption is returning `nil`.

Any help on why this is not working would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the if statement?

Comment: Nothing. Nothing comes up even if I remove the if statement. @Dustin Rowland

Comment: I checked my buffer and it is 0x783c5d0. I believe it has something to do with the Encrypt method on the web service not matching the iPhone decryption.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you have a couple of problems here:

1. You are specifying an IV when encrypting, but you are leaving it
   NULL when decrypting. While it's true that the IV is optional, you
   must use the same one for encrypting and decrypting.
2. I'm pretty sure you are not parsing the key correctly when
   decrypting. From what I can tell, you seem to be using a
   double-base64 encoded string (for some reason) on the server. At
   least, this is what I see you doing with it:

   ```
   1. Base64 decoding the string.

   2. Splitting the resulting string on ','.

   3. Taking the first part of the split, base64 decoding it again to use as the IV.

   4. Taking the second part of the split, base64 decoding it again to use as the key.
   ```

   You aren't doing any of these things in the Obj-C code. And assuming that you are taking in the key in the same format, you need to. All you are doing in the Obj-C code is taking the NSString object and converting it into a C-string.

Comment: How can I use base64 encoding on the server? I thought thats what `Convert.FromBase64String` did.

Comment: Yes, you are base64 decoding the key on the server. But you aren't base64 decoding the key in the Objective-C code.

Comment: So instead of `NSUTF8Encoding` use base64 encoding. Is there something like that?